# Fragment instance error

Tags: android, fragment

I use fragment in layout file,but it say Fragment cannot be instantiated.This problem only occur when my Fragment extends from android.support.v4.Fragment,no problem when extends from android.app.Fragment. And I want to support android1.6,how could I solve this problem?

Here is my error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.text/com.example.text.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at com.example.test.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.test.ui.NavigationDrawerFragment that is not a Fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): ... 20 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
E/AndroidRuntime(24647): ... 25 more
```

Here is my code:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<fragment
android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:name="com.example.test.ui.NavigationDrawerFragment"
android:layout_width="240dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Class:

```
package com.example.test.ui;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.test.R;

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
return view;
}

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.test.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.jinlin.deliverybox.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity code? I think you are trying to inflate the wrong layout.

Comment: Already posted.I think the layout is right.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as a variable declaration:

```
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft;
```

Add this to your init views

```
mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

// Set up the drawer.
mNavigationDrawerFragmentLeft.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

Comment: The layouts anmes might not be correct because I don't know what your fragment layout is called. However, the activity should call the id of the fragment in your activity_main.xml file

Comment: I don't think so.I import android.app.Fragment instead android.support.v4.app.Fragment,every thing is ok.I guess activity treat <fragment..> as android.app.Fragment and I use v4.Fragment,so it's confliced

Comment: Is your navigation fragment support v4 too?

Comment: Seems no.I want it support v4.

Comment: Use FragmentActivity will avoid this problem,thank you all the same.